# Contacts app in Android 7.1 claims that I have no images on my device

Tags: contacts, 7.1-nougat, motorola-moto-z2-play

On my Motorola Moto Z2 Play with stock version of Android 7.1.1 currently I have:

- 188 photos in DCIM > Camera folder,
- 10 pictures in Pictures > Contacts folder,
- 5 pictures in Pictures > Icons folder,
- 24 pictures in Pictures > Wallpapers folder.

Yet, when I am trying to assign a new photo for one of my newly created contacts (Google Account) in Contacts app it claims that I have no images in my device and does not open a file browser / does not allow me to pick any photo for given contact:

[image]

What am I missing here? How to workaround this weird problem and be able to pick a photo for any contact (other way than using PC for this purpose)?

Comment: Did you check that the contacts app has the "Access Photos and Videos" permission?

Comment: Yes, it has (though it is called just "Storage" in Android 7.1.1 with details explaining that this allows app to read files on my SD card). It actually has all requested permissions enabled. For testing purposes I have revoked this permission and tried to add photo using above way -- no change, still the same message.